# Javascript popup in html table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, popup

I have a 10 x 10 with data table that is created using html tags. If it is possible to create a onClick function to each cell? I mean, if I click on a cell, then it gives me its value in a  n alert window? If yes, then how?

Comment: do you use jquery or another javascript framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plain JS - assuming `<table id="table1">`:

```
window.onload=function() {
  var cells = document.getElementById('table1').getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (var i=0, n=cells.length;i<n;i++) {
    cells[i].onclick=function() { alert(this.innerHTML) }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good example could be found here

```
HTML CODE: 

<div id='page-wrap'>

Your content goes here.

<a id='show' href='#'>show overlay</a>
```

---

```
JavaScript & JQuery:

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#show").click(function() {
    showPopup();
});

$("#popup").click(function() {

    $(this).hide();
    $("#mask").hide();

});
```

});

function showPopup() {

```
   // show pop-up

$("#mask").fadeTo(500, 0.25);

// show the popup
$("#popup").show();
}



 ---------------------------------------


 CSS CODE: 


* { margin: 0, padding 0}

#mask{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #000;
display: none;
z-index: 10000;
```

}

```
#popup
{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
margin: 10px auto; 
border: 1px solid #333;
background-color: #ffffdd;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 10px;
position: relative;
z-index: 10001;
display: none;
}


  [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: You should add a section of the code that answers the question in SO instead of just pasting a link.

Comment: @JeremyW: Thank you for the comment, I did not post a link before. and I'll make sure to do post the code it self instead of the link.